# Lack of resolution on merging into a grid a ggplot graph and a table obtained by flextable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to merge via `plot_grid` a plot obtained with `ggplot2` and a table obtained using `flextable()`. I saw from other questions the procedure to make the conversion as raster, but I realized by doing that a loss on the resolution of the table. The lines become too much thicker. I would like to have the original resolution flextable that in my view is much nicer. Is it possible?

[image]

Below the original code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggthemes)
library(patchwork)
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)
library(cowplot)
library(flextable)


#generic, reproducible data
Graph1 <- data.frame(x = 1:100, y = runif(100))

Graph <- ggplot(Graph, aes(x = x)) + geom_line(aes(y = y)) + scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) #control axis parameters






`Sample name` <- c("Media1", "Media2")
`Valore medio Peel (N)` <- c(4.35, 4.31)
`Valore massimo Peel (N)` <- c(5.5, 6.5)
df <- data.frame(`Sample name`, `Valore medio Peel (N)`, `Valore massimo Peel (N)`) 


df <- flextable(df)
df <- set_header_labels(df, Sample.name = "Sample name", `Valore.medio.Peel..N.` = "Valore medio peel (N)", `Valore.massimo.Peel..N.`= "Valore massimo Peel (N)")
df <- set_table_properties(df, layout = "autofit", width = .6)
df <- bold(df, bold = TRUE, part = "header")
df

##webshot::install_phantomjs() ##To be installed if needed

df <- as_raster(df, zoom = 2)
df <- ggplot() + theme_void() + annotation_custom(rasterGrob(df), xmin=-Inf, xmax=Inf, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf)


plot_grid(Graph, df, labels = NULL, ncol = 1, nrow = 2, scale = c(1, .75))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `zoom = 1` in the `as_raster()` call. Here are the resulting images from setting `zoom = 1` vs `zoom = 2`:

```
df <- as_raster(df, zoom = 1)
```

[image: zoom1]

```
df <- as_raster(df, zoom = 2)
```

[image: zoom2]